# How do I send data to multiple Kafka producers one time

Tags: apache-kafka

I am looking for a help on Kafka producer to multiple clusters in parallel. I have two environments for pushing data to (cert and dev), every time I run producer to send data to cert and dev separately (one topic), is there away I can send data to both clusters together?

Answer (score 1):

Tying your application (producers) to a particular environment topology (cert / dev) doesn't sound like the best approach. There is no way to produce from the same producer instance to two clusters - so then you would have to have two producer instances, and hope that both behave exactly the same when producing. Any problems (e.g. network glitch) that causes one to fail and the other not means you end up with divergence in your two environments.

Instead use something like [Confluent Replicator](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-replicator/index.html) or [MirrorMaker 2](https://blog.cloudera.com/a-look-inside-kafka-mirrormaker-2/) to stream records from one cluster to another. That way you can build your application to producer records to a target cluster, and decoupled from that populate additional environments/clusters as desired.